# What happend when i assign an iterator to a variable

Tags: python, iterator

I define a list *i*, which is iterable. As the code shows, an iterator will be returned When it calls *__iter__()* method. But when i call its *next()* method four times, it just prints 1 four times, not 1,2,3,4.

```
>>> i=[1,2,3,4]  
>>> i.__iter__  
<method-wrapper '__iter__' of list object at 0x04040378>  
>>> i.__iter__()  
<listiterator object at 0x040561F0>
>>> i.__iter__().next()  
1  
>>> i.__iter__().next()  
1  
>>> i.__iter__().next()  
1  
>>> i.__iter__().next()  
1
```

So i do something blow:)

```
>>>ite=i.__iter__()
>>>ite.next()
1
>>>ite.next()
2
>>>ite.next()
3
>>>ite.next()
4
>>> ite.next()

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#23>", line 1, in <module>
    ite.next()
StopIteration
```

Could anybody tell me the difference between these two ways? Tx a lot :)

Comment: You ask for *four iterators* in the first version.

Comment: Thank u. I get it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every time you call `__iter__` you get a new iterator.  In your first example, you call `__iter__` four times, so you are getting four new iterators, and you call `next` once on each, so you always get the first value.  In your second example you are calling `__iter__` once, so you only get one iterator, and you call `next` four times on that same iterator, so you get all four values.

Comment: Oh my bad. The four iterators are at different adresses ;D  thanks.